# How difficult is it to port an existing webapp to Google TV?

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-tv

I'm thinking about attending a Google TV hackathon event later this week, and I have no experience with Google TV. It seems that Android is the main platform to build on, but I want to run my existing web app on Google TV. I was wondering how difficult of a job it is, and if it's something that can be done over a weekend. Can anyone provide advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on what your webapp does.  If it uses Flash, or not.  There are lots of things to consider before doing just a "port".  On the other hand, if your really interested in that, you might wish to look at this article I wrote:  [Moving Web Content to Google TV Android Apps](https://developers.google.com/tv/android/articles/moving_web_content_to_android)  If your app isn't already D-pad navigable, you might be interested in the [jQuery & Closure extensions](https://developers.google.com/tv/web/docs/tools_libraries) as well as our template libraries.

Chrome on Google TV is Chrome 11 w/ security patches.  A [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) hasn't really changed in quite a while.  If you've got significant CSS3 usage, you'll notice it.

Comment: You mentioned "If it uses Flash, or not." Is using Flash easier? Or worse? My app uses Youtube...

Comment: Flash isn't supported in a WebView (Only in Chrome).

Answer (score 5):

Android is *a* platform to build on for GoogleTV, and it has some advantages, but GoogleTV also has Chrome built in. You can put your web app on Chrome first, and migrate to Android afterwards.

I think the key success factor for any app on Google TV is adherence to the design guidelines. Regardless of which platform you use, you need to design for a 10 foot environment and a mouseless control system. Remember:

- TV is a passive environment: People want to watch more and interact less.
- People are sitting far away from the screen. Visual processing changes.
- TV is more of a group environment.
- You are guaranteed a D-pad on a remote control, nothing more.
- Very high audio and video quality is expected
- Your app is competing with what's on TV.

Answer (score 0):

To port existing website to optimized version for Google TV, the key ingredient is use some Javascript library to make your sites D-pad navigable. There are a couple of libraries jQuery and Closure available: https://developers.google.com/tv/web/docs/tools_libraries.

If your site has video content, the easiest way is focus on them and leverage on the Google TV Templates available here: https://developers.google.com/tv/web/docs/gtv-templates.

If videos content you have is relatively static, you may hard code them into your web pages, as done in the Templates above.  But if they change often and you'd like to have a backend with an admin page to manage them using e.g. MySQL, read this article to see how it can be done: https://developers.google.com/tv/web/docs/ajax_gtv_templates_tutorial

You can host videos on your own server or play them directly from YouTube. If you need the Javascript to play them from YouTube, let's start a new thread.